# How to set the condition on crystal report to filter data?

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and the database is using MySQL database. How to filter the data in the database to put into the report? I want to filter the data from VB program. Does it possible? Thank you a lot!

Comment: please write your question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on the Formula Fields option in the Field Explorer and
  select New...
- Enter a suitable formula field name.
- In the Formula editor, enter a formula as you want like:

  If {table1.xyz} = 'TRUE' then 1
- Use  `Alt-C` to check that the formula does not have
  any errors, then press the Save and Close button to exit the formula
  editor.
- Drag and drop the new formula field from the Field Explorer onto
  anywhere in the report.

Comment: But how if i want to set the conditions based on vb toolbox? For example, select * from (tablename) where id = '" + checkbox1.text + "

Comment: do you understand this? Hehe